# Content beyond whitespaces in string values passed using extra-vars dropped

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am trying to pass a comma-separated string using the `--extra-vars` flag. Doing so works as expected, that I can split the string on the `,` and iterate over the resultant list within the jinja template:

```
ansible-playbook test_before_role.yml \
-e DNS_SERVER="153.64.251.202,153.64.251.201" \
--inventory=qa_vm_inventory.yml
```

Since this playbook is invoked from Jenkins, I want to be certain that any whitespaces inadvertently input would be gracefully taken care of.

```
ansible-playbook test_before_role.yml \
-e DNS_SERVER="153.64.251.202, 153.64.251.201 " \
--inventory=qa_vm_inventory.yml
```

The below is my jinja template.

```
{% for host in DNS_SERVER.split(',') %}
nameserver {{ host }}
{% endfor %}
```

Does ansible not like white-spaces as part of extra-vars? Or am I overlooking something? Some answers would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using '-e', you really need to quote the string (whilst it might sort of work with one variable, if you ever want to pass more than one, you will definitely need to quote), so change it to this and it should work:

```
ansible-playbook test_before_role.yml \
  -e "DNS_SERVER='153.64.251.202, 153.64.251.201 '" \
  --inventory=qa_vm_inventory.yml
```

You can then trim the split elements:

```
{% for host in ( DNS_SERVER.split(',') | map('trim') | list ) %}
nameserver {{ host }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you, that trimming and piping to list is something I wasnt aware of.